# Laravel cannot find public dir

Tags: php, laravel

I worked on a team and then clone the laravel/php codes from our repository. When I serve the laravel on localhost, it cannot find all the file inside the `public` directory and throw an error on the terminal:

```bash
[404]: GET /public/css/style.css - No such file or directory
```

Many answers to similar issues advise me to change the codes in the `blade.php` file. The problem is that I can't edit the `blade.php` because it works fine on other team members even though we have the same ubuntu, PHP, and laravel version and `.env` file.

What I have tried:

- Run `composer install` and `composer update`
- Try different browsers such as firefox and chromium-based browsers
- Run `php artisan storage:link`
- Restart apache2
- Run `npm install` and `npm run dev`

I think there is some package or something missing.

List of paths I get from `dd($__data)`:

```
"path" => "/project-directory/project-name/app"
"path.base" => "/project-directory/project-name"
"path.lang" => "/project-directory/project-name/resources/lang"
"path.config" => "/project-directory/project-name/config"
"path.public" => "/project-directory/project-name/public"
"path.storage" => "/project-directory/project-name/storage"
"path.database" => "/project-directory/project-name/database"
"path.resources" => "/project-directory/project-name/resources"
"path.bootstrap" => "/project-directory/project-name/bootstrap"
```

Comment: Did you check log file?

Comment: You're supposed to config Apache so that `/public` points to the web root. And in this manner files like .env, composer.json, and readme.md are not within reach of the web.

Comment: @KevinY could you clarify what you mean or maybe tell me what should I do to "config Apache so that `/public` points to the web root"?

Comment: Did you tried manually create that file and test it ?

Comment: @fatm the file is exist, I don't need to create it

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried?

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Comment: I have, it returns `The [public/storage] directory has been linked.` But, the error is still there.

Comment: have you compared your .env file with your coworker? Search in your config folder does it contain database.php as well app.php?

Comment: Could you edit the blade.php file to see what the output is or the path using dd?

Comment: No problem regarding the `.env` file or any other files

Comment: could you dd the path in the blade file and tell us what it says?

Comment: I edit the question to add the paths if that is what you mean. For running `php artisan key:generate`, of course I did. For `composer auto-load`, I don't think there is such command, it returns: `Command "auto-load" is not defined. `

Comment: I mean by running composer dump-autoload as well as php artisan config:clear

Answer (score 0):

You need first run

```
php artisan storage:link
```

For more details check https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem

Then you must be check your .env values.
Is correctly `APP_URL=`

Also in your exception is strange

```
/public/.../...
```

Reason is wrong configuration.
First check your .env values like

```
APP_URL=...
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=public
```

then check config/filesystems.php

Comment: My exception means that there are several lines of `[404] GET /public/ - No such file or directory` error. I edited the exception on my question.

Comment: run npm install and npm run dev

Comment: `npm install` and `npm run dev` returns `**DONE** Compiled Successfully` but the errors still there.